# Appending Multiple Fields In Twig

Tags: 8, theming

I'm attempting to append two fields with some text in the middle. Using the changed date and a plain, core, text field, I can do something like this, and it works:

```
{{ node.changed.value|date('m.d.y') ~ ' | By, '}}{{ content.field_author_name.0 }}
```

However, if I attempt to do that in a single tag, the changed date, and the 'By' text is output, but I don't get the author name field.

```
{{ node.changed.value|date('m.d.y') ~ ' | By, ' ~ content.field_author_name.0 }}
```

Is that not valid twig syntax, or is there something else needed to get that to work in a single statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `{{ content.field_author_name.0 }}` it works because field is rendered with the twig.
[The *~* operator](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html#other-operators) converts all operands into strings and concatenates them. Given that `content.field_author_name.0` is a render array you need point to the string value of this field. To do this you can inspect it with the devel or [twig_vardumper](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_vardumper) module using `dump(content.field_author_name.0)`. More about debugging twig templates: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates#s-viewing-variables

Assuming that *field_author_name* is simple text field with the *Plain text* formatter, this should work:

```
{{ node.changed.value|date('m.d.y') ~ ' | By, ' ~ content.field_author_name.0['#context'].value }}
```

To display node creator name you can use this:

```
{{ node.changed.value|date('m.d.y') ~ ' | By, ' ~ node.uid.entity.name.value }}
```

Comment: That clears it up for me. I had dumped that variable out and seen the context array and value field and assumed it should be pulling the value behind the scenes. Didn't realize the ~ operator was converting the value directly to a string before Drupal got ahold of it.

Answer (score 0):

To get the author name you can use `{{ node.Owner.name.value }}` or `{{ node.uid.entity.name.0.value }}`.
Try with:

```
{{ node.changed.value|date('m.d.y') ~ ' | By, ' ~ node.Owner.name.value }}
```